# SFML can't load an image

Tags: c++, sfml

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Sprites!");

    sf::Texture playerTex;
    playerTex.loadFromFile("Textures/player_ship.png");

    sf::Sprite playerSprite;
    playerSprite.setTexture(playerTex);
    playerSprite.setScale(1.5, 1.5);
    playerSprite.setPosition(100, 100);
    playerSprite.setOrigin(32, 32);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(playerSprite);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, SFML opens a blank window (it should have a sprite) and when this window closes, it returns the error `Failed to load image "`.

I have the Textures folder located in multiple directories so it should be able to see it. I've already tried re-copying the textures and reinstalling SFML. How do I fix it??

Comment: Please don't link to code. Put the relevant code directly into the question in [mcve] form.

Comment: Try this: ```playerTex.loadFromFile("./Textures/player_ship.png");```

Comment: @ArthurLodbrock How would that help? If a path starts with a slash it is absolute, else it is relative to the current directory. As OP's path does not start with a slash, it is relative to the current directory. So prepending  it with dot, which means *"the current directory"* brings absolutely nothing to the party, surely?

Comment: Maybe your PNG image is 16-bit, or palettised or something SFML doesn't like. Try running `pngcheck -v player_ship.png` on it to see what it is. `pngcheck` ships with `libpng`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had such a problem when I switched my OS. When I wanted to open a file in Windows I wrote ```folder\\file```. But the program was not able to find my file when I wrote  ```folder/file``` in Linux. Then I changed it to ```./folder/file``` and it worked.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I know the image is a proper format, because some other people have used it with the same VS/SFML.

Comment: Does using absolute path work? Do you know what the path of your working directory is? Are you sure you have the `Textures` directory in your working directory?

Comment: Only finding out that your image did not load correctly when you close the program is the reason you should be checking the return value of loadFromFile().

Comment: Absolute paths do not work, and the dir is in my working directory.